# Should I be using a reporting framework?

Tags: java, collections, reporting, criteria, rules

For the purposes of explaining what it is I'm trying to do, take the classic banking example.

I have a stream of payments coming in from one bank account to another. I would like users of my web app to be able to create their own predicates to filter payments that will form the input data to some reports. I was planning on writing the reports manually rather than with an existing reporting framework.

In order of priority, the types of predicates I'd like users to be able to create with a web front end are:

1. `payment.amount > 100.0`
2. `payment.amount > 100.0 || payment.dayOfWeek = TUESDAY`
3. `(payment.amount > 100.0 && payment.description.contains("foo")) || payment.dayOfWeek = TUESDAY`

I would also like to be able to persist these predicates for reuse at a later date.

I feel this must be such a common requirement that at least some of this must have been developed already but I'm finding it hard to pinpoint what it is I'm trying to search google for. Has anyone come across either a web-based framework for generating the predicates and/or something for persisting this data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [Drools](http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines/drools) for creating and re-using business rules.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at drools. I used jrules a while ago which had decision trees / tables / rules; I feel it might be overkill from a few perspectives - development, ruleset deployment, user learning curve to create new rules/datasets. What I've been looking for is a form that has a combobox containing, say, 'Amount', 'Day Of Week', another combo 'contains', 'is equal', 'is in list', which drives the generation of final value field(s), e.g. textbox, combo, list etc. An add button then saves the current "rule" and start another. It does sound like a rules engine putting it like that!

Answer (score 0):

A business rules engine could be a good solution, but might also be oversized.

There are a lot rules engines on the market and they differ a lot. For instance, http://openrules.com is excel heavy where as drools is more the developer kind of rules engine (see http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines for a big list of engines).

Even embedding a scripting language like groovy could be a good solution.

Bit if you really only need those three rules which you've described, I guess It would make sense to just store those three parameters (amount, searchTerm and weekday) and build a DB query with them.